# Only certain PHP files can send GET requests to file?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay,

SO little by little I'm tackling the challenger of learning PHP. I'm understanding it more and more each time I play around with it.

The thing that is making me a little hesitant is security.

How would I be able to deny direct access to a file and only allow a specific file be able to access/send GET requests/ execute queries?

I'm setting up a config file and a index.php file and basically I will have the index.php connect using the config file.

```
<?php

// MySQL Credentials
define('DATA_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATA_NAME', 'mysql');
define('DATA_USER', 'mysql');
define('DATA_PASS', 'mypass');

 try {
   $connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DATA_HOST .';dbname='.DATA_NAME, DATA_USER, DATA_PASS);
   $connection->SetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo '<h2>PDO unable to connect to database!</h2>';
 }


?>
```

That's my current config file, using PDO as I've heard it's secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I did more digging around and I found the solution.

```
if( !defined( 'SOMETHING', 1 ) )
{
    echo( '<h1>You may not access this file directly.</h1>' );
    exit;
}
```

^ on the config file and then.

```
define( 'SOMETHING', 1 );
```

^ on the file that wants to include the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, PDO is only secure if you use it properly - make sure to use prepared statements to pass in ALL data. Use it incorrectly and it's still insecure.

If you want to prevent users from directly loading a file, you have a few options.

The best is to simply have them entirely outside of your document root. Then there is no worry. This makes deployments difficult though.

The next best is to use htaccess (or the equivalent on your chosen http server) to block public access to entire subfolders containing your code. In my projects I put all my code under a single folder named "private", and all the public files outside of that, so I can just block the private folder entirely.

A second option is to use a define to tell the rest of your code the user entered through the index file. At the top of index.php add `define( 'INDEX_PASSED', true );` or something, and then in your other files at the top you can simply do `if( !defined( 'INDEX_PASSED' ) ) exit;`. This is dangerous though as you will have to remember to do it in EVERY file. The previous method is much better.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be hesitated of.

Direct access to this file will do no harm at all.

While with all this useless "protection" you are just bloating your code with no reason.